# Grunt 'watch' command not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

When I run the `grunt watch` task in my terminal, it doesn't seem to be picking up any changes when I modify files.

I'm not sure if it's my file structure or the configuration in my `Gruntfile.js`. Can anyone let me know what I have done wrong?

```
   sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed',
                require: 'susy'
            },
            files: {
                'app/styles/css/main.css': 'app/styles/sass/main.scss'
            }
        }
    },

    css: {
        files: ['css/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
        }

    },
     watch: {

        css: {
            files: 'app/styles/sass/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass'],
            options: {
                livereload: true,
            },
        }

    }

});


grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sprite-generator');
grunt.registerTask('watchfiles', ['sass',  'watch' ]);
```

[image: file structure]

Comment: And you are typing `grunt watchfiles` or `grunt watch` on command line?

Comment: @KJPrice yes i am, i forgot to mention

Comment: Wel, I think that `livereload` needs to go under `options` parameter per [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload). Also, I'd make sure that this is the correct path to your css "app/styles/css/".

Comment: @KJPrice annoying, i am still not seeing actions occurring in my terminal when i make changes to my sass files

Comment: try 
`grunt.registerTask('watchfiles', ['sass',  'watch:css' ])`;

Comment: Which sass files should trigger the "watch" tasks? main.scss? the ones in app/styles/sass/atoms? All of them?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want watch to listen for changes to the .scss files in the atoms subdir, in your watch css task config change `files: 'app/styles/sass/*.scss'` to `files: 'app/styles/sass/**/*.scss'`

Right now you are only watching files with the extension .scss which are also immediate children of your sass directory. Adding the two asterisks `**/*.scss` tells grunt-contrib-watch that you want to watch all of the files with the exention .scss in the sass dirs subdirs recursively.

The suggestion in the comments under you question to create a task called `watchfiles` is not a good one, in my opinion. That suggestion is to promote task naming which is overly generic and not descriptive of what the task does, and creates an extra layer which is simply unnecessary.

To eliminate any other layers, which add uncertainty, when testing whether this works or not, invoke the `watch:css` task directly by running the command `grunt watch:css` in the same directory as your `Gruntfile.js`, make changes, and observe results.